# Angular 4 Cannot match any routes, escaping with %2F

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an issue with routing in my angular 4 project.
When I try to navigate to a path like: `ticketBlocks/new` I see this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'ticketBlocks%2Fnew'

Angular escapes the '/' and of course doesn't match, is it possible to use this path without that escape?

This is my **app.routing**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
.
.
.
 {
   path: 'ticketBlocks/new',
   loadChildren: './ticket-blocks/ticket-block-new/ticket-block-
   new.module#TicketBlockNewModule'
  },
.
.
```

my **sidebar**

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [{
.
.
.
{
    path: '/',
    title: 'Magazzino',
    type: 'sub',
    icontype: 'assignment_turned_in',
    children: [
        { path: 'ticketBlocks/new', title: 'Nuovi blocchi', ab: 'NB' },
        { path: 'ticketBlocks/movements', title: 'Spostamenti', ab: 'SP' }
    ]
},
```

**sidebar.ts**

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public menuItems: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        let isWindows = navigator.platform.indexOf( 'Win' ) > -1 ? true : false;
        if ( isWindows ) {
            // if we are on windows OS we activate the perfectScrollbar function
            const $sidebar = $( '.sidebar-wrapper' );
            $sidebar.perfectScrollbar();
        }
        this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter( menuItem => menuItem );
        isWindows = navigator.platform.indexOf( 'Win' ) > -1 ? true : false;

        if ( isWindows ) {
            // if we are on windows OS we activate the perfectScrollbar function
            $( '.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper, .main-panel' ).perfectScrollbar();
            $( 'html' ).addClass( 'perfect-scrollbar-on' );
        } else {
            $( 'html' ).addClass( 'perfect-scrollbar-off' );
        }
    }
```

And this is the **sidebar.html**

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuitem of menuItems">
<!--If is a single link-->
<a [routerLink]="[menuitem.path]" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'">
<i class="material-icons">{{menuitem.icontype}}</i>
<p>{{menuitem.title}}</p>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Post the code where you're routing somewhere? Or are you typing this into your browser?

Comment: @Z.Bagley question updated

Comment: Where do you set `menuItems`? Need to see that as well

Comment: @Z.Bagley sorry edited again

Comment: Path is inside sidebar Routes, in sidebar.ts I do menuitems=Routes...all other path works...only when there is a '/' I have this problem

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the cause of the error (my guess is the string might be non-utf-8 or something to that effect). A sure way to get around this is to use the non-template `this.router.navigate([' ... '])`.
**html** `<a (click)="customRoute(menuitem.path)" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'">`
**component ts**
`import { Router } from '@angular/router';  constructor( private router: Router) { } customRoute(route) {let routeArray = route.split('/');     this.router.navigate(routeArray);}`
May have missed syntax on the route params, but basic idea is there.